# how to initialise a matrix

Tags: c#

how can I initialise a matrix with `System.Drawing.Drawing2D`;

I Tried this:

```
private Matrix Rb = new Matrix (  );
```

But It give me just the Identity Matrix while I need this matrix:

```
(a, 0 ,0; 0 , a,0, 0,0,a)
```

How can I itnitialise this matrix to have the possibility the to use functions like Invert rotate etc.?

Comment: Try the other overloads . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You actually can't set the values in the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can't set the values in the 3rd column. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> In GDI+ you can store an affine transformation in a Matrix object. Because the third column of a matrix that represents an affine
>   transformation is always (0, 0, 1), you specify only the six numbers
>   in the first two columns when you construct a Matrix object.

To set the first two columns you use the [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0616edf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with six numbers to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

The `Matrix` class encapsulates a 3-by-3 affine matrix.

And you can initalize it like that: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0616edf(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(m11, m12, m21,m22, dx,dy);
```

All of the values are `floats`

- `m11`: The value in the first row and first column of the new Matrix.
- `m12`: The value in the first row and second column of the new Matrix.
- `m21`: The value in the second row and first column of the new Matrix.
- `m22`: The value in the second row and second column of the new Matrix.
- `dx`: The value in the third row and first column of the new Matrix.
- `dy`: The value in the third row and second column of the new Matrix.